# Can't run git project in eclipse after cloning the project

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've been following this guide to set up a git environment in eclipse for a java project, but I could not get rid of this error.
I seemed to work, since i can now see the repository in repository view, and I am able to perform all basic git commands (always through gui, since i am on Windows and i am not used to this OS).

Then I Build the project and seems to works (there are some errors relative to other used projects and jars or library, but it has always worked and are not important), until I Run and it does not work at all and the only thing it says is

Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale myPackage.MyMainClass

i belive the problem is related to git and classpath, since git projects are not stored inside workspace, they are in the git folder, and inside them no bin is present.

i don't even know now where are the .class supposed to be created, wether in the workspace or in git folder, neither i know what to write in the .classpath to link (if it is right) to the correct project location... since i have a lot of projects i should edit all of them?

Please, I need help!! :'(

Comment: "This guide"? [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26796231/edit) and put in the link

Comment: Since you have not made it clear that what environment are you using I assume Java on eclipse standard edition. 
Go to Project menu and check if "Build Automatically" is ticked, then refresh the project and "Clean and Build" or "Clean" depending on git version. It is recommended that you use git bash for git and Hg not GUI.